# Unity using shader for water effect but I need the normal and location of the shader triangle not the mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am working on a game and I bought a water shader, I am just to time strapped to learn it right now. I am making a game with water and ships. I need the ships to respond to the water shader vertex normal at the ray cast hit position. Frankly I just don't know what I am doing and I would appreciate any help.
**Shader**

```
Shader "StylizedWater/Mobile"
{
    Properties
    {
        [HDR]_WaterColor("Water Color", Color) = (0.1176471,0.6348885,1,0)
        [HDR]_WaterShallowColor("WaterShallowColor", Color) = (0.4191176,0.7596349,1,0)
        _Wavetint("Wave tint", Range( -1 , 1)) = 0
        [HDR]_RimColor("Rim Color", Color) = (1,1,1,0.5019608)
        _NormalStrength("NormalStrength", Range( 0 , 1)) = 0.25
        _Transparency("Transparency", Range( 0 , 1)) = 0.75
        _Glossiness("Glossiness", Range( 0 , 1)) = 0.85
        [Toggle]_Worldspacetiling("Worldspace tiling", Float) = 1
        _NormalTiling("NormalTiling", Range( 0 , 1)) = 0.9
        _EdgeFade("EdgeFade", Range( 0.01 , 3)) = 0.2448298
        _RimSize("Rim Size", Range( 0 , 20)) = 5
        _Rimfalloff("Rim falloff", Range( 0.1 , 50)) = 3
        _Rimtiling("Rim tiling", Float) = 0.5
        _FoamOpacity("FoamOpacity", Range( -1 , 1)) = 0.05
        _FoamSpeed("FoamSpeed", Range( 0 , 1)) = 0.1
        _FoamSize("FoamSize", Float) = 0
        _FoamTiling("FoamTiling", Float) = 0.05
        _Depth("Depth", Range( 0 , 100)) = 30
        _Wavesspeed("Waves speed", Range( 0 , 10)) = 0.75
        _WaveHeight("Wave Height", Range( 0 , 1)) = 0.5366272
        _WaveFoam("Wave Foam", Range( 0 , 10)) = 0
        _WaveSize("Wave Size", Range( 0 , 10)) = 0.1
        _WaveDirection("WaveDirection", Vector) = (1,0,0,0)
        [NoScaleOffset][Normal]_Normals("Normals", 2D) = "bump" {}
        [NoScaleOffset]_Shadermap("Shadermap", 2D) = "black" {}
        [Toggle(_USEINTERSECTIONFOAM_ON)] _UseIntersectionFoam("UseIntersectionFoam", Float) = 0
        [Toggle]_ENABLE_VC("ENABLE_VC", Float) = 0
        [Toggle(_LIGHTING_ON)] _LIGHTING("LIGHTING", Float) = 0
        [Toggle]_Unlit("Unlit", Float) = 0
        _Metallicness("Metallicness", Range( 0 , 1)) = 0
        [Toggle(_NORMAL_MAP_ON)] _NORMAL_MAP("NORMAL_MAP", Float) = 0
        [Toggle]_USE_VC_INTERSECTION("USE_VC_INTERSECTION", Float) = 0
        [Toggle]_EnableDepthTexture("EnableDepthTexture", Float) = 1
        [HideInInspector] __dirty( "", Int ) = 1
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Transparent"  "Queue" = "Transparent+0" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "ForceNoShadowCasting" = "True" }
        LOD 200
        Cull Back
        CGPROGRAM
        #include "UnityPBSLighting.cginc"
        #include "UnityShaderVariables.cginc"
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        #pragma target 3.0
        #pragma multi_compile __ _LIGHTING_ON
        #pragma multi_compile __ _NORMAL_MAP_ON
        #pragma shader_feature _USEINTERSECTIONFOAM_ON
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
        #pragma exclude_renderers xbox360 psp2 n3ds wiiu 
        #pragma surface surf StandardCustomLighting alpha:fade keepalpha noshadow nolightmap  nodynlightmap nodirlightmap nometa noforwardadd vertex:vertexDataFunc 
        struct Input
        {
            float3 worldPos;
            float4 screenPos;
            float4 vertexColor : COLOR;
            float2 vertexToFrag713;
            float2 vertexToFrag714;
            float3 worldRefl;
            INTERNAL_DATA
            float3 vertexToFrag746;
            float3 worldNormal;
        };

        struct SurfaceOutputCustomLightingCustom
        {
            half3 Albedo;
            half3 Normal;
            half3 Emission;
            half Metallic;
            half Smoothness;
            half Occlusion;
            half Alpha;
            Input SurfInput;
            UnityGIInput GIData;
        };

        uniform sampler2D _Normals;
        uniform sampler2D _Shadermap;
        uniform half _WaveHeight;
        uniform float _ENABLE_VC;
        uniform float _Worldspacetiling;
        uniform float _WaveSize;
        uniform float _Wavesspeed;
        uniform float4 _WaveDirection;
        uniform float _EnableDepthTexture;
        uniform sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
        uniform half _EdgeFade;
        uniform half _Transparency;
        uniform float _Depth;
        uniform half4 _WaterShallowColor;
        uniform float4 _RimColor;
        uniform float _USE_VC_INTERSECTION;
        uniform half _Rimfalloff;
        uniform float _Rimtiling;
        uniform half _RimSize;
        uniform float _NormalTiling;
        uniform half _NormalStrength;
        uniform half _Glossiness;
    

uniform float _Unlit;
        uniform half4 _WaterColor;
        uniform half _Wavetint;
        uniform half _FoamOpacity;
        uniform float _FoamTiling;
        uniform float _FoamSpeed;
        uniform half _FoamSize;
        uniform float _WaveFoam;
        uniform float _Metallicness;

        void vertexDataFunc( inout appdata_full v, out Input o )
        {
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT( Input, o );
            float3 ase_vertexNormal = v.normal.xyz;
            float4 VertexColors729 = lerp(float4( 0,0,0,0 ),v.color,_ENABLE_VC);
            float3 ase_worldPos = mul( unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex );
            float2 Tiling21 = lerp(( -20.0 * v.texcoord.xy ),( (ase_worldPos).xz * float2( 0.1,0.1 ) ),_Worldspacetiling);
            float2 appendResult500 = (float2(_WaveDirection.x , _WaveDirection.z));
            float2 WaveSpeed40 = ( ( _Wavesspeed * _Time.x ) * appendResult500 );
            float2 HeightmapUV581 = ( ( ( Tiling21 * _WaveSize ) * float2( 0.1,0.1 ) ) + ( WaveSpeed40 * float2( 0.5,0.5 ) ) );
            float4 tex2DNode94 = tex2Dlod( _Shadermap, float4( HeightmapUV581, 0, 1.0) );
            float temp_output_95_0 = ( saturate( ( _WaveHeight - (VertexColors729).b ) ) * tex2DNode94.g );
            float3 Displacement100 = ( ase_vertexNormal * temp_output_95_0 );
            v.vertex.xyz += Displacement100;
            o.vertexToFrag713 = lerp(( -20.0 * v.texcoord.xy ),( (ase_worldPos).xz * float2( 0.1,0.1 ) ),_Worldspacetiling);
            o.vertexToFrag714 = ( ( _Wavesspeed * _Time.x ) * appendResult500 );
            #if defined(LIGHTMAP_ON) && ( UNITY_VERSION < 560 || ( defined(LIGHTMAP_SHADOW_MIXING) && !defined(SHADOWS_SHADOWMASK) && defined(SHADOWS_SCREEN) ) )//aselc
            float4 ase_lightColor = 0;
            #else //aselc
            float4 ase_lightColor = _LightColor0;
            #endif //aselc
            o.vertexToFrag746 = ase_lightColor.rgb;
            
        }

        inline half4 LightingStandardCustomLighting( inout SurfaceOutputCustomLightingCustom s, half3 viewDir, UnityGI gi )
        {
            UnityGIInput data = s.GIData;
            Input i = s.SurfInput;
            half4 c = 0;
            //Start - Stylized Water custom depth
            float4 ase_screenPos = float4( i.screenPos.xyz , i.screenPos.w + 0.00000000001 );
            float4 ase_screenPosNorm = ase_screenPos / ase_screenPos.w;
            ase_screenPosNorm.z = ( UNITY_NEAR_CLIP_VALUE >= 0 ) ? ase_screenPosNorm.z : ase_screenPosNorm.z * 0.5 + 0.5;
            float screenDepth795 = LinearEyeDepth(UNITY_SAMPLE_DEPTH(tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture,UNITY_PROJ_COORD(ase_screenPos))));
            float distanceDepth795 =  ( screenDepth795 - LinearEyeDepth( ase_screenPosNorm.z ) ) / (  lerp( 1.0 , ( 1.0 / _ProjectionParams.z ) , unity_OrthoParams.w) );
            #if SHADER_API_MOBILE && UNITY_VERSION >= 20183 //Build only, abs() function causes offset in depth on mobile in 2018.3
            #else
            distanceDepth795 = abs(distanceDepth795);
            #endif
            //End - Stylized Water custom depth
            float DepthTexture494 = distanceDepth795;
            float ColorDepth479 = lerp(1.0,saturate( ( DepthTexture494 / _Depth ) ),_EnableDepthTexture);
            float4 VertexColors729 = lerp(float4( 0,0,0,0 ),i.vertexColor,_ENABLE_VC);
            float2 Tiling21 = i.vertexToFrag713;
            float2 temp_output_24_0 = ( Tiling21 * _Rimtiling );
            float2 WaveSpeed40 = i.vertexToFrag714;
            float temp_output_30_0 = ( tex2D( _Shadermap, ( ( 0.5 * temp_output_24_0 ) + WaveSpeed40 ) ).b * tex2D( _Shadermap, ( temp_output_24_0 + ( 1.0 - WaveSpeed40 ) ) ).b );
            float Intersection42 = saturate( ( _RimColor.a * ( 1.0 - ( ( ( lerp(lerp(1.0,DepthTexture494,_EnableDepthTexture),( 1.0 - (VertexColors729).r ),_USE_VC_INTERSECTION) / _Rimfalloff ) * temp_output_30_0 ) + ( lerp(lerp(1.0,DepthTexture494,_EnableDepthTexture),( 1.0 - (VertexColors729).r ),_USE_VC_INTERSECTION) / _RimSize ) ) ) ) );
            float Opacity121 = saturate( ( ( lerp(1.0,saturate( ( DepthTexture494 / _EdgeFade ) ),_EnableDepthTexture) * saturate( ( ( _Transparency * saturate( ( ColorDepth479 + _WaterShallowColor.a ) ) ) + Intersection42 ) ) ) - (VertexColors729).g ) );
            float3 ase_worldPos = i.worldPos;
            #if defined(LIGHTMAP_ON) && UNITY_VERSION < 560 //aseld
            float3 ase_worldlightDir = 0;
            #else //aseld
            float3 ase_worldlightDir = normalize( UnityWorldSpaceLightDir( ase_worldPos ) );
            #endif //aseld
            half3 _BlankNormal = half3(0,0,1);
            float2 temp_output_705_0 = ( _NormalTiling * Tiling21 );
            #ifdef _NORMAL_MAP_ON
                float2 staticSwitch760 = ( ( float2( 0.25,0.25 ) * temp_output_705_0 ) + WaveSpeed40 );
            #else
                float2 staticSwitch760 = float2( 0,0 );
            #endif
            #ifdef _NORMAL_MAP_ON
                float2 staticSwitch761 = ( temp_output_705_0 + ( 1.0 - WaveSpeed40 ) );
            #else
                float2 staticSwitch761 = float2( 0,0 );
            #endif
            #ifdef _NORMAL_MAP_ON
                float3 staticSwitch763 = ( ( UnpackNormal( tex2D( _Normals, staticSwitch760 ) ) + UnpackNormal( tex2D( _Normals, staticSwitch761 ) ) ) / float3( 2,2,2 ) );
            #else
                float3 staticSwitch763 = _BlankNormal;
            #endif
            float3 lerpResult621 = lerp( _BlankNormal , staticSwitch763 , _NormalStrength);
            float3 NormalMap52 = lerpResult621;
            float dotResult741 = dot( ase_worldlightDir , normalize( WorldReflectionVector( i , NormalMap52 ) ) );
            float GlossParam754 = _Glossiness;
            float3 lerpResult478 = lerp( (_WaterShallowColor).rgb , (_WaterColor).rgb , ColorDepth479);
            float3 WaterColor350 = lerpResult478;
            float2 HeightmapUV581 = ( ( ( Tiling21 * _WaveSize ) * float2( 0.1,0.1 ) ) + ( WaveSpeed40 * float2( 0.5,0.5 ) ) );
            float4 tex2DNode94 = tex2D( _Shadermap, HeightmapUV581 );
            float Heightmap99 = tex2DNode94.g;
            float3 temp_cast_0 = (( Heightmap99 * _Wavetint )).xxx;
            float3 RimColor102 = (_RimColor).rgb;
            float3 lerpResult61 = lerp( ( WaterColor350 - temp_cast_0 ) , ( RimColor102 * 3.0 ) , Intersection42);
            float2 temp_output_634_0 = ( WaveSpeed40 * _FoamSpeed );
            float4 tex2DNode67 = tex2D( _Shadermap, ( ( _FoamTiling * Tiling21 ) + temp_output_634_0 + ( Heightmap99 * 0.1 ) ) );
            #ifdef _USEINTERSECTIONFOAM_ON
                float staticSwitch725 = ( 1.0 - tex2DNode67.b );
            #else
                float staticSwitch725 = saturate( ( 1000.0 * ( ( tex2D( _Shadermap, ( ( _FoamTiling * ( Tiling21 * float2( 0.5,0.5 ) ) ) + temp_output_634_0 ) ).r - tex2DNode67.r ) - _FoamSize ) ) );
            #endif
            float Foam73 = ( _FoamOpacity * staticSwitch725 );
            float3 temp_cast_1 = (2.0).xxx;
            float FoamTex244 = staticSwitch725;
            float WaveFoam221 = saturate( ( pow( ( tex2DNode94.g * _WaveFoam ) , 2.0 ) * FoamTex244 ) );
            float3 lerpResult223 = lerp( ( lerpResult61 + Foam73 ) , temp_cast_1 , WaveFoam221);
            float3 FinalColor114 = lerpResult223;
            #ifdef _LIGHTING_ON
                float3 staticSwitch769 = float3( 0,0,0 );
            #else
                float3 staticSwitch769 = ( saturate( ( pow( max( 0.0 , dotResult741 ) , ( GlossParam754 * 128.0 ) ) * GlossParam754 ) ) + lerp(( i.vertexToFrag746 * FinalColor114 ),FinalColor114,_Unlit) );
            #endif
            float3 CustomLighting753 = staticSwitch769;
            SurfaceOutputStandard s733 = (SurfaceOutputStandard ) 0;
            s733.Albedo = FinalColor114;
            s733.Normal = WorldNormalVector( i , NormalMap52 );
            s733.Emission = float3( 0,0,0 );
            s733.Metallic = _Metallicness;
            s733.Smoothness = GlossParam754;
            s733.Occlusion = 1.0;

            data.light = gi.light;

            UnityGI gi733 = gi;
            #ifdef UNITY_PASS_FORWARDBASE
            Unity_GlossyEnvironmentData g733 = UnityGlossyEnvironmentSetup( s733.Smoothness, data.worldViewDir, s733.Normal, float3(0,0,0));
            gi733 = UnityGlobalIllumination( data, s733.Occlusion, s733.Normal, g733 );
            #endif

            float3 surfResult733 = LightingStandard ( s733, viewDir, gi733 ).rgb;
            surfResult733 += s733.Emission;

            #ifdef UNITY_PASS_FORWARDADD//733
            surfResult733 -= s733.Emission;
            #endif//733
            #ifdef _LIGHTING_ON
                float3 staticSwitch734 = surfResult733;
            #else
                float3 staticSwitch734 = CustomLighting753;
            #endif
            c.rgb = staticSwitch734;
            c.a = Opacity121;
            return c;
        }

        inline void LightingStandardCustomLighting_GI( inout SurfaceOutputCustomLightingCustom s, UnityGIInput data, inout UnityGI gi )
        {
            s.GIData = data;
        }

        void surf( Input i , inout SurfaceOutputCustomLightingCustom o )
        {
            o.SurfInput = i;
            o.Normal = float3(0,0,1);
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}
```

**My Code**

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        LayerMask mask = LayerMask.GetMask("ignore");
        Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, mask);
        MeshCollider meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;
        if (!(meshCollider == null || meshCollider.sharedMesh == null))
        {
            Mesh mesh = meshCollider.sharedMesh;
            mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            Vector3[] normals = mesh.normals;
            int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

            // Extract local space normals of the triangle we hit
            Vector3 n0 = normals[triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0]];
            Vector3 n1 = normals[triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1]];
            Vector3 n2 = normals[triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2]];

            // interpolate using the barycentric coordinate of the hitpoint
            Vector3 baryCenter = hit.barycentricCoordinate;

            // Use barycentric coordinate to interpolate normal
            Vector3 interpolatedNormal = n0 * baryCenter.x + n1 * baryCenter.y + n2 * baryCenter.z;
            // normalize the interpolated normal
            interpolatedNormal = interpolatedNormal.normalized;

            // Transform local space normals to world space
            Transform hitTransform = hit.collider.transform;
            interpolatedNormal = hitTransform.TransformDirection(interpolatedNormal);

            // Display with Debug.DrawLine
            Debug.DrawRay(gameObject.transform.position, interpolatedNormal * 10f, Color.black);
        }
        //0-1 on max speed
        currentShipScalar = ((shipSpeed - (shipSpeed - Body.velocity.magnitude)) / (shipSpeed));
```

this only returns the mesh normal not the shader. I used this [enter link description here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/stylized-water-shader-71207)

and this [enter link description here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-barycentricCoordinate.html)

as my code source. I feel dumb I am just exhausted. I don't like that I have not yet understood whats going on but I have a dead line of one week. any help would be apreciated.

Comment: shader complete https://mail.meatcupgames.org/s/RqjQWTYWicGkfof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset you are using is just a shader. Changes in the vertex position inside a shader are just on the GPU and can not be accessed by the CPU. The asset also states, it does not support Buoyancy, so it really just is a visual thing.

To be able to access the wave distortion you either need to have a compute shader or some other preprocessing step that calculates your changes for you, which are used afterwards inside you wave shader.

[More information on the same problem](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1671703/cannot-get-vertex-position-after-vertex-shader-has.html)

Might be worth taking a look at another solution (maybe the [boat attack repo](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/BoatAttack) would be a good fit), but I don't know your target device and scope of the project (I guess you're on builtin renderer right now).

Comment: Makes sense, looks like the easy way is to just recreate the noise generator in script. that I can do. I'm still a noob when it comes to shaders, I was taught it like 2 years ago but I just don't remember any more lol. anyway at least with this I don't have to raycast woot.